# How to get the all the columns which the datatype is not int or float with python pandas?

Tags: pandas

I want to change the dataframe to numpy.ndarray with datatype float32, so I want to drop those column which dtype is object or other type which is not number.

Comment: in other words, you're looking for numeric columns? you could do `df._get_numeric_data()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.select_dtypes(include=['int', 'float'])
```

will do it for you. There's also an `exclude` option.